# How to insert records in sqlite3 table (on rails), with sql code?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I found in internet a SQL file that contain all the Cities with this structure :

```
INSERT INTO cities 
SET id=1,city='name_of_city',zip_code=XXXXX,province='XX',region='name_of_region';
```

So, i create a 'cities' table in Rails (sqlite3) with the same structure:

```
Cities : Id, city(char), zip_code, province, region.
```

Now, how can i use this SQL file with rails to populate my table ??
Is there a tool to convert "SQL INSERT RECORD" for sqlite3 database ?

Thanks

EDIT (Some lines of SQL file)

```
INSERT INTO cities SET id=1,city='Abano Terme Bagni',zip_code=35031,province='PD',region='Veneto';
INSERT INTO cities SET id=2,city='Abatemarco',zip_code=84040,province='SA',region='Campania';
INSERT INTO cities SET id=3,city='Abazia Di Sulmona',zip_code=67030,province='AQ',region='Abruzzo';
INSERT INTO cities SET id=4,city='Abbadia Alpina',zip_code=10060,province='TO',region='Piemonte';
```

Comment: Not sure I understand but are you looking for an ORM like ActiveRecord?

Comment: No, he is looking for something to inport all the data from a file to his database. Did you think about doing it with regex and imporiting it through Ruby objects to the database? what does your data look like, can you give examples of the first 2 or 3 rows

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan I create a Cities table in Rails and now i would like to insert in it all the Italian city, but in internet i only found MYSQL files with all cities. Can i convert MYSQL statements to insert all the cities in SQLITE3 database ?

Comment: @Zippie I had also thought about a script to change the sql file and then place the result in the table, but do not know where to start ... I edited my answer with some lines of SQL file .

Comment: @iRails - you need to be specific. I would recommend that you look for data rather than scripts, and generate the inserts in sqlite format. There are plenty of datasets available.

Comment: Anyways, i don't know of any programs that would do something like that for you, but have you tried c/p insertions in the sqlite3 client? But even a better approach would be to checkout how to make seeds, so you can load them on any environment you are. Cause if you store them now, they won't be there in the production phase

Answer (score 0):

I think you could generate the mysql db, then use a dumping gem like [seed_dump](https://github.com/zenprogrammer/seed_dump) or [yaml_db](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db) and you could have all the data for use it with any db engine for your rails apps.